# Distance chessboard / camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, euclidean-distance

I'm estimating the distance using a chessboard and `solvePnP` function from `openCV`.

I heard that to have the more accurate distance, I shouldn't have the chessboard parallel to the image plan because the real change of distance in front of the camera doesn't have the same scale in the image because of the perspective.

[image]

For example if I move the chessboard `1cm` far from the camera probably the size of the chessboard (in the image) won't be very noticeable to the camera hence the distance won't be very accurate in that situation.

Is that true and is there any books or references about this fact?